# Show custom taxonomy in theme

Tags: plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, filters

How do I show a custom taxonomy in the same places as the theme that is set to display category.

I had the same problem with custom posts and solved using 'pre_get_posts' and $ query-> set ('post_type', array ('post', 'custom-post'))

Is there the same thing for custom taxonomy?

[image: List of categories created with category]

In Categories it is listing the categories created with category. I also want to list my custom_taxonomy_category categories

Comment: Are those sidebar widgets? Search the plugin repository for a custom taxonomy widget.

Comment: @milo Not only in the side bar but anywhere in the theme that requests categories.
get_the_category_list () ... get_category () or anything like that.

I want to override the normal category request so that only my custom taxonomy is listed.

I want themes, plugins, treat my custom taxonomy as if it were the default category of wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list out the custom taxonomy you have to use  [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function

For your requirement instead of creating new taxonomy you can modify the default category it self

```
function custom_change_cat_object() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Author';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Author';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Author';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Author';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Author';
    $labels->new_item = 'Author';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Author';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Authors';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Authors found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Authors found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Authors';
    $labels->menu_name = 'Author';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Author';
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_change_cat_object' );
```

Comment: I'm using in a plugin not in a theme. I need the modification without making changes to the theme.

Comment: @BrunoAndrade your Question is not much detailed..try to update your question with more details. are you creating the custom taxonomy using plugin? you can use the same code in the theme as well as plugin. You can create a simple widget and place it on sidebar widget area (not sure whether you have shown a sidebar screenshot in your question)

Comment: it's simple I created a custom taxonomy and now I want everywhere in the site where the categories of the deafult taxonomy "category" are listed, also the categories of my custom taxonomy are listed. But I want to do this without changing the theme. I guess I have to use a filter but I do not know how.

Comment: whether the categories are hard coded? i think it is shown with widgets. so what you can do is create a simple widget with in your plugin and place it below categories

Comment: Not only in the side bar but anywhere in the theme that requests categories.
get_the_category_list () ... get_category () or anything like that.

I want to override the normal category request so that only my custom taxonomy is listed.

I want themes, plugins, treat my custom taxonomy as if it were the default category of wordpress

Comment: to my knowlege the wordpress executes in an order. You can't place a filter unless you don't know the where you want to apply filter. I don't know why your theme creator has hard coded category list ? could you share the links to your website

Comment: For your requirement i have updated the answer